# No instance for (Show (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of `print'

Tags: haskell, lambda

I try to implement a basic lambda function but struggle with some mistakes and can't figure out the solution after searching between the questions here. My code is:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap addSomething [] = []
myMap addSomething (x:xs) = addSomething x : myMap addSomething xs

-- instance Show (a -> b) where
--          show a = "funcion"

list = [0..4]
listTwo = [(5 :: Int)..9]

addSomething :: Int -> Int
addSomething x = x + 1

addSomethingTwo ::  Num a => a -> a-> a
addSomethingTwo x = (\x->x+1)

main = do
    print $ myMap addSomething list
    print $ myMap addSomethingTwo listTwo
```

and here is the error message I get

```
 No instance for (Show (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Int -> Int))
    In the expression: print
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ myMap addSomethingTwo listTwo
    In the expression:
      do { print $ myMap addSomething list;
           print $ myMap addSomethingTwo listTwo }
```

if I uncomment these lines

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
         show a = "function"
```

I get this strange result

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[function,function,function,function,function]
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

thank you in advance,
Tamas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

addSomethingTwo have a function (Int -> Int) as a result, not Int

You need function definition as

```
addSomethingTwo x = (\x->x+1) x
```

Or, to clear that x in lambda and in function parameter are different variables (they are in different scopes):

```
addSomethingTwo y = (\x->x+1) y
```

Answer (score 3):

`myMap addSomethingTwo listTwo` generates a list of functions. It has type `[Int->Int]`, since `addSomethingTwo` is a binary function `a->(a->a)` (provided `Num a`), which means that it takes a number of type `a` and returns a numerical function `a->a`, thanks to currying. Those functions `a->a` get put in the list by `map`.

Functions can not be printed by default, as the error message reports: "no `Show` instance for `Int -> Int`. Your commented `Show` instance allows functions to be printed as "`function`".

I have little idea on what you are actually trying to achieve.